# invalid parameter error for sql multi insert function

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Can't seem to figure out what the problem is with this.  I have used this same method before, but not with the inner for each for each user.  I am getting an `Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: parameter was not defined'`, but from what I can see everything matches up correctly.

I have `user_id` and `day` setup as a unique key group in the db.  $output has stored values (1 or 0) for every hour of the day for each day of the week.  This entire week of values of each hour are inserted for each user on a per day basis (only the user_id and day values change for the inserts).

```
$user_set = array(1, 5, 8, 24) //user ids to insert for

$weekdays = array(1 => 'mon', 2 => 'tue', 3 => 'wed', 4 => 'thu', 5 => 'fri', 6 => 'sat', 7 => 'sun');

$hourDefs = array('12am', '1am', '2am', '3am', '4am', '5am', '6am', '7am', '8am', '9am', '10am', '11am', '12pm', '1pm', '2pm', '3pm', '4pm', '5pm', '6pm', '7pm', '8pm', '9pm', '10pm', '11pm');


//build query for multi insert
$sql = 'INSERT INTO weekly_sched (
        user_id,
        day,
        12a,
        1a,
        2a,
        3a,
        4a,
        5a,
        6a,
        7a,
        8a,
        9a,
        10a,
        11a,
        12p,
        1p,
        2p,
        3p,
        4p,
        5p,
        6p,
        7p,
        8p,
        9p,
        10p,
        11p
    ) VALUES ';

$sqlDupe = 'ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
    12a = VALUES(12a),
    1a = VALUES(1a),
    2a = VALUES(2a),
    3a = VALUES(3a),
    4a = VALUES(4a),
    5a = VALUES(5a),
    6a = VALUES(6a),
    7a = VALUES(7a),
    8a = VALUES(8a),
    9a = VALUES(9a),
    10a = VALUES(10a),
    11a = VALUES(11a),
    12p = VALUES(12p),
    1p = VALUES(1p),
    2p = VALUES(2p),
    3p = VALUES(3p),
    4p = VALUES(4p),
    5p = VALUES(5p),
    6p = VALUES(6p),
    7p = VALUES(7p),
    8p = VALUES(8p),
    9p = VALUES(9p),
    10p = VALUES(10p),
    11p = VALUES(11p)
';

//set starting values
$insertQuery = array();
$insertData = array();
$n = $n2 = 0;

//build bindings for user for each day
foreach ($user_set as $key)
{       
    // loop through each weekday
    foreach($weekdays as $day=>$day_value)
    {
        //build day values for the user
        $insertQuery[] = '(
            :user_id'.$n.'-'.$n2.',
            :day'.$n.'-'.$n2.',
            :12a'.$n.'-'.$n2.',
            :1a'.$n.'-'.$n2.',
            :2a'.$n.'-'.$n2.',
            :3a'.$n.'-'.$n2.',
            :4a'.$n.'-'.$n2.',
            :5a'.$n.'-'.$n2.',
            :6a'.$n.'-'.$n2.',
            :7a'.$n.'-'.$n2.',
            :8a'.$n.'-'.$n2.',
            :9a'.$n.'-'.$n2.',
            :10a'.$n.'-'.$n2.',
            :11a'.$n.'-'.$n2.',
            :12p'.$n.'-'.$n2.',
            :1p'.$n.'-'.$n2.',
            :2p'.$n.'-'.$n2.',
            :3p'.$n.'-'.$n2.',
            :4p'.$n.'-'.$n2.',
            :5p'.$n.'-'.$n2.',
            :6p'.$n.'-'.$n2.',
            :7p'.$n.'-'.$n2.',
            :8p'.$n.'-'.$n2.',
            :9p'.$n.'-'.$n2.',
            :10p'.$n.'-'.$n2.',
            :11p'.$n.'-'.$n2.'
        )';
        $insertData['user_id'.$n.'-'.$n2] = $key;
        $insertData['day'.$n.'-'.$n2] = $day;
        $insertData['12a'.$n.'-'.$n2] = $output[$day_value]['12am'];
        $insertData['1a'.$n.'-'.$n2] = $output[$day_value]['1am'];
        $insertData['2a'.$n.'-'.$n2] = $output[$day_value]['2am'];
        $insertData['3a'.$n.'-'.$n2] = $output[$day_value]['3am'];
        $insertData['4a'.$n.'-'.$n2] = $output[$day_value]['4am'];
        $insertData['5a'.$n.'-'.$n2] = $output[$day_value]['5am'];
        $insertData['6a'.$n.'-'.$n2] = $output[$day_value]['6am'];
        $insertData['7a'.$n.'-'.$n2] = $output[$day_value]['7am'];
        $insertData['8a'.$n.'-'.$n2] = $output[$day_value]['8am'];
        $insertData['9a'.$n.'-'.$n2] = $output[$day_value]['9am'];
        $insertData['10a'.$n.'-'.$n2] = $output[$day_value]['10am'];
        $insertData['11a'.$n.'-'.$n2] = $output[$day_value]['11am'];
        $insertData['12p'.$n.'-'.$n2] = $output[$day_value]['12pm'];
        $insertData['1p'.$n.'-'.$n2] = $output[$day_value]['1pm'];
        $insertData['2p'.$n.'-'.$n2] = $output[$day_value]['2pm'];
        $insertData['3p'.$n.'-'.$n2] = $output[$day_value]['3pm'];
        $insertData['4p'.$n.'-'.$n2] = $output[$day_value]['4pm'];
        $insertData['5p'.$n.'-'.$n2] = $output[$day_value]['5pm'];
        $insertData['6p'.$n.'-'.$n2] = $output[$day_value]['6pm'];
        $insertData['7p'.$n.'-'.$n2] = $output[$day_value]['7pm'];
        $insertData['8p'.$n.'-'.$n2] = $output[$day_value]['8pm'];
        $insertData['9p'.$n.'-'.$n2] = $output[$day_value]['9pm'];
        $insertData['10p'.$n.'-'.$n2] = $output[$day_value]['10pm'];
        $insertData['11p'.$n.'-'.$n2] = $output[$day_value]['11pm'];

        // increase for next day
        $n2++;
    }
    // increase for next user
    $n++;
}

if (!empty($insertQuery)) {
    $sql .= implode(', ', $insertQuery);
    $sql .= ' '.$sqlDupe;
    $stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->execute($insertData);
        }
```

Comment: certainly not cleaned up, but easier to view and work with this way...

Comment: I wonder if PDO doesn't like parameter names that begin with a number.

Comment: @Barmar - previously I was doing this in a loop with `$stmt = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO weekly_sched (user_id, day, 12a, 1a, 2a, 3a, 4a, 5a, 6a, 7a, 8a, 9a, 10a, 11a, 12p, 1p, 2p, 3p, 4p, 5p, 6p, 7p, 8p, 9p, 10p, 11p) VALUES (:user_id, :day, :12a, :1a, :2a, :3a, :4a, :5a, :6a, :7a, :8a, :9a, :10a, :11a, :12p, :1p, :2p, :3p, :4p, :5p, :6p, :7p, :8p, :9p, :10p, :11p)");` which worked fine so I don't see why the above would be different.

Comment: I don't think you can use hyphen in a parameter name, use underscore instead. Hyphen is the subtraction operator.

Comment: That was it!  Good find... I did not know about that... figured it was okay since it was within quotes... thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change all the hyphens in the parameter names to underscores. For instance,

```
        :user_id'.$n.'-'.$n2.',
```

should be:

```
        :user_id'.$n.'_'.$n2.',
```

It's interpreting this as `:user_id$n minus $n2`.